# Check for unwanted wildcard dependencies recursively

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a library and want to make sure that none of the dependencies in my dependency-tree uses wildcard dependencies. Wildcard dependencies are evil :(

Can I check this recursively with `cargo` in the command line? Or can I check it manually in `Cargo.lock`?

**EDIT**: While `crates.io` rejects crates with wildcard dependencies since the release Rust 1.6 ([approximately](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/01/21/Rust-1.6.html), thanks Steve Klabnik), there are still old crates on `crates.io` that *do* have wildcard dependencies. I can upload my own crate that depends on such an old crate. Therefore my crate indirectly also depends on wildcard dependencies. This is what I want to avoid and check for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a small script that takes the [crates.io-index](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index) and reads the current information for all packages. If a package has a direct wildcard dependency on another package there is a line printed in the format `crate-name -> wildcard-dependency, another-one`.

There are [995 current packages with wildcard dependencies](https://gist.github.com/pyfisch/563c6e64b57492c92bf399a495064660). The list is exhaustive and will only decrease in length if the packages are updated.

You can go manually through all dependencies in your Cargo.lock and check if they are mentioned in the list. Note that you must use the most current version of your dependencies to assure that you are not depending on an outdated package with wildcard dependencies.

Comment: So... this is just checking the direct dependencies? So if my crate depends on `crate-a`, which depends on `crate-b`, which has a wildcard dependency, then: (1) `crate-b` is listed in your list (2) looking up the dependencies of my crate (namely `[crate-a]`) won't help me. Did I understand correctly? If yes, it would be awesome if you could do this recursive stuff and/or publish your script. :)

Comment: You have to check all dependencies mentioned in "Cargo.lock". The initial text had a typo that said "Cargo.toml". But this only works if all dependencies use up-to-date dependencies. :-(

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense I guess. Could you still post your script? I would certainly be interested in it. Also: I think I will ping the [cargo-outdated](https://github.com/kbknapp/cargo-outdated) guys and ask if they want to integrate this feature...

Comment: Here is the [script that generated the list](https://gist.github.com/pyfisch/a535fec885dd4efb2f77b4c4fd6ebd3b). The cargo-outdated people can probably better implement it since doing it properly requires knowledge of semver to determine the correct version of all dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

As of a few months back, Cargo no longer allows for wildcard dependencies. So you don't need to do this yourself.

This is a crates.io feature, not a Rust or Cargo feature, so it's not associated with any particular version of these tools. The update happened [around the time we released Rust 1.6](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/01/21/Rust-1.6.html).

Comment: Do you have the (stable) version of the Cargo/Rust release which first activated this? It would allow users using older releases knowing whether it's "fixed" in their release or not.

Comment: That's exactly my problem: my library had an old dependency that still uses wildcard dependencies. I can still publish my crate to `crates.io`, because it doesn't use wildcard dependencies directly, but only through one other crate. So with a huge dependency tree I want to check whether or not anything in this tree still uses wildcard dependencies.